# Laravel 5 how to modify default Date accessors?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

I have a code like this:

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value) {
    setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));
    return Carbon::parse($value)->formatLocalized(__('DateFormat'));
}
```

I want to run this accessor for each field specified in `$dates` array instead of manually specifying it for each date field in each model, just like default `Carbon` instance convertion works. How could I do this? And is there better ways of specifying default locale-dependant date format for `Carbon`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an elegant and simple solution: [LocalizedCarbon](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon) package. It works as simply as this:

```
use \Laravelrus\LocalizedCarbon\Traits\LocalizedEloquentTrait;
```

**UPD:** It seems that this package actually translating only DateDiff's, but anyway I can see how it works and use that logic in my models.

**UPD2:** I've dig deeper and found out what there is overloaded `formatLocalized` method, which allows useage of non-standard "%f" parameter, which represents month name in current application locale. So I ended up with one-liner date formatting into my `View` instead of `Model`, which is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use $dateFormat variable of a model to apply a common date format on all the model fields:

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: But this variable is used for `format` method, but I need `formatLocalized` method instead.